# unable to use a compact style of module and class under test folder (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zeitwerk

I have folder insider `test/fixtures/schemas` where I define some schemas that I use to validate the JSON response of some controllers like this:

```
test
  |
  |
  controllers
  |
  |
  ....
  fixtures
         |
         |
         organizations.yml
         |
         |
         schemas
               |
               |
               clients
                     |
                     |
                     show.rb
               |
               |
               organizations
               ...
```

the file under `fixtures/schemas/client/show.rb` looks like this:

```rb
module Clients
  class Show < Dry::Validation::Contract
    json do
      required(:id).filled(:string)
      required(:state).filled(:string)
...
```

it works fine and I can use this schema on my tests with `Clients::Show` but we also have a rubocop rule that enforces us to use compact module and class style like this:

```rb
class Clients::Show < Dry::Validation::Contract
```

but when I define it like this, I get a `NameError`

```
test/fixtures/schemas/client/show.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Client (NameError)
```

I find it weird that one structure works and the other doesn't. I read through the Zeitwerk manual but couldn't anything that would explain my problem, and tried different things like defining a `client.rb` file with an empty module but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions are not the same.

```
module Clients
  class Show
```

defines a module with the name `Clients` *and* a class `Show` in the namespace `Clients`. But

```
class Clients::Show
```

only defines a class `Show` in the namespace `Clients`. There isn't automatically a module with the name `Clients` defined in this case.

Comment: yes, of course! Ruby 101 that I keep forgetting hahaha thanks!